# RMA link in the my account area not visible

Tags: magento

I am having trouble seeing the RMA link in the orders area. We are running Magento Enterprise version 1.14.1.0. I have enabled RMA returns in the system configuration area as well as enabled it on the front end. Only the “Print Order” and "Reorder" link is showing up.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or have any suggestions at all? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is RMA enabled on your order? Also you need to have shipped the item already.

Comment: Yes RMA link enabled on orders

Comment: Yes. RMA enabled for the ordered items but still the link not appearing on the order page